# Google Drive API: no downloadURL for *.zip file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a zip file through the Google Drive Rest API in Python, but my API call does not return a downloadURL. The code I'm using is still pretty close to the official documentation.

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
results= service.children().list(folderId=shapes_folder).execute()
items = results.get('items', [])
shape_ids = []
if not items:
    print 'No files found.'
else:
    for item in items:
        shape_ids.append(item['id'])
print shape_ids
all_files = service.files().list().execute()
items = all_files.get('items', [])
if not items:
    print 'No files found.'
else:
    for item in items:
        if item['title'] == shape_file_name:
            shape_file_id = item['id']
            shape_file = service.files().get(fileId=shape_file_id).execute()
            print shape_file
            download_url = shape_file["downloadUrl"]
            print download_url
            if download_url:
                resp, content = service._http.request(download_url)
                if resp.status == 200:
                    print 'Status: %s' % resp
                    return content
                else:
                    print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
                    return None
            else:
            # The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                return None
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it or http://www.clevernote.co/app/drivecrud.html to fetch the File resource and see if it's there.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's there. Any clue what's wrong with the method I'm using?

Comment: Was a scope problem. The metadata-scope doesn't provide the downloadURL. Continued using this method despite the piece documentation you referenced since my version of the Python API Client does not seem to have the MediaIoBaseDownload method.